# Problema al insertar datos en la base de datos desde PHP

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos, oracle

Mi problema es que al insertar datos en la base de datos desde PHP, el campo **fecha** me la registra como `0027-02-19` y cuando inserto directamente desde la base de datos, me lo registra como debe ser, es decir, `2019-02-27`. ¿Que puede estar pasando?

`SQL insert` directamente desde la base de datos:

```
INSERT INTO MRCJ000 (NBCLI000,G300CTA,C001CLIN,CUUID000,UIDEJE000,FULTACT000,USFHPRO,IDALDF000) 
VALUES('victor', 123456, '124', '22', '10', TO_DATE(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), TO_DATE(sysdate, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), '0')
```

Insert desde `PHP`:

```
$stid = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO MRCJ000 (NBCLI000,G300CTA,C001CLIN,CUUID000,UIDEJE000,FULTACT000,USFHPRO,IDALDF000) 
                                                VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), ?)");
                        $stid->bindParam(1, $clientes_enviar[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);
                        $stid->bindParam(2, $cuentas_enviar[$i], PDO::PARAM_INT);
                        $stid->bindParam(3, $codCliente[$i], PDO::PARAM_STR, 50);                   
                        $stid->bindParam(4, $canal, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);                    
                        $stid->bindParam(5, $gerente, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);                    
                        $stid->bindParam(6, $aliado, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);                
                        $stid->execute();
                        $stid->closeCursor();
```

Dejo la imagen de la base de datos:

[image: Datos al insertar]

Comment: ¿Que pinta la etiqueta de MySQL aqui si es Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No es necesario hacer `to_date` a una fecha. 
Es convertir una fecha a una fecha; considerando que ésta función es sensible a la configuración del lenguage y territorio. En caso necesario debes usar el tercer parámetro de la función.

Comment: `SYSDATE` regresa tipo `DATE`. El tipo `TIMEDATE` no existe en Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `CURDATE()` en lugar de `TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD')`
`CURDATE()` te retorna la fecha en formato 'YYYY-MM-DD'.